# grails pagination max results

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm wondering how you set the max pagination results, with my code below it continues to set the max results to the default of 10. I'd like 25. Any thoughts?

```
def list(Integer max) {

    def recoverySetupList = RecoverySetup.createCriteria().list {
            'in'("division", userService.getDivisions())
            maxResults(Math.min(max ? : 25, 100))
            firstResult(params.offset ? params.int('offset') : 0)

            if( params.sort && params.order ) {
                if(params.sort != 'peNameU') {
                    order params.sort, params.order
                } else {
                    oneSolName {
                        order params.sort, params.order
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    respond recoverySetupList, model:[recoverySetupInstanceCount: RecoverySetup.count()]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be setting it right.  Should work, so the problem is elsewhere, e.g. where is the default max of 10 is set, is `max` assigned any value, what about `params.max`?

You can try passing max and offset into the list - ..`createCriteria().list(max: max, offset: offset)` and remove `maxResults` and `firstResult` from the body of the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code works fine for first time (when no max is supplied) but when you press any pagination link then it is set to 10. If so then you have to set the max in pagination tag as well, like

```
<g:paginate max="25" total="${recoverySetupInstanceCount}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please use this

```
            params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 25, 100)
            int offset = 0;
            if(params.offset != null) {
                offset = (Integer.valueOf(params.offset));
            }
```